# ImportError: cannot import name 'RequestsTransport' from 'azure.core.pipeline.transport'

Tags: python, docker, azure-sdk-python

I have a python program I am trying to run in a Docker container, that is consistently throwing an import error.

The program file looks like this:

```py
import logging
import sys

from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient

QUEUE_NAME = "{QUEUE_NAME}"

CONNECTION_STRING = "{CONNECTION_STRING}"
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

def receive_message(message_func: callable) -> ():
    """
    :param message_func: a function that takes a dict as its argument representing the message payload and operates on it
    :return:
    """
    with ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(
        conn_str=CONNECTION_STRING
    ) as servicebus_client:
        with servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME) as receiver:
            messages = receiver.receive_messages()
            for message in messages:
                try:
                    message_func(json.loads(str(message)))
                    receiver.complete_message(message)
                except Exception:
                    logging.exception(
                        f"Failed to process message: {message.message_id}"
                    )


def process_as2_message(as2_message: dict) -> ():
    '''
    :param as2_message: dictionary representing the message payload
    :return:
    '''
    message_payload_subject = as2_message["subject"]
    blob_url = message_payload_subject.replace(MESSAGE_SUBJECT_PREFIX, "")
    with BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(
        BLOB_SECRETS.connection_string
    ) as blob_service_client:
        with blob_service_client.get_container_client(
            BLOB_SECRETS.container_name
        ) as container_client:
            try:
                payload_downloader = container_client.download_blob(blob_url)
                payload_content = payload_downloader.readall()
                logging.info(
                    f"Successfully Downloaded message payload for message: {blob_url}"
                )
                logging.info(f"Message content: {payload_content}")
                # TODO: process transformation on message here
            except Exception:
                logging.exception("Failed to download message payload")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == "readiness":
        sys.exit(0)

    while True:
        logging.info("Processing messages from queue")
        service_bus.receive_message(process_as2_message)
```

The goal is to run this in k8s. I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13

RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add --update cmake gpgme-dev libc-dev python3 py-pip python3-dev cmake gcc g++ openssl-dev build-base git curl perl-dev linux-headers bash

ENV CONTAINER_HOME=/usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/queue
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/config

COPY *.py /usr/src/app/
COPY *.txt /usr/src/app/

RUN python3 -m pip install -q --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r $CONTAINER_HOME/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

CMD [ "python3", "./main.py"]
```

The requirements.txt files contains:
azure-common
azure-core
azure.identity
azure-storage-blob
azure-storage-common

The error I am receiving is: `ImportError: cannot import name 'RequestsTransport' from 'azure.core.pipeline.transport' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/transport/__init__.py)`

I also tried this using an ubuntu and manylinux (manylinux is the target for building uamqp, a native wheel dependency of service bus), and I get the same error.  In the docker container in a shell, I am able to cat the file in the exception message and see that the class is present in that directory, so I KNOW that it is there.  I took this Docker config from another service we have that uses these dependencies and it works fine.

What can be causing this? I verified that there is only a single python environment on the image.  I am able to consistently reproduce in the container in a python shell and in my own local mac.  The dependency is literally there in the directory and I can see it, why can't python?

UPDATE:
output from running `pip show azure-storage-blob` in docker:

```
Name: azure-storage-blob
Version: 12.17.0
Summary: Microsoft Azure Blob Storage Client Library for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob
Author: Microsoft Corporation
Author-email: ascl@microsoft.com
License: MIT License
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: azure-core, cryptography, isodate, typing-extensions
Required-by: 
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core $
```

Opening a python shell in docker container and printing `sys.path` shows `['', '/usr/local/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue today. Please make sure that the name of any of the files in your project is not matching the name of a library you are trying to use (E.G requests.py).

This was causing the issue for me. Renaming the file fixed the issue.

Hope it helps;
Kind Regards

Comment: I resolved the issue, the above code interfacing with the service bus was in a module called "queue", which overwrote a module with the same name in urllib, which is a dependency of the azure sdk.  Changing the name of the module resolved the issue.